# If #REF! is found then Error Box Macro

Tags: excel, vba, find, msgbox

I am trying to complete a simple macro that looks for '#REF!' in a worksheet due to a user alterting a row and ruining underlying formulas.

I have got as far as the find:

```
Sheets("Location_Multiple").Select
Range("A1:AL10000").Select

Selection.Find(What:="#REF!", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

From what I understand I need to enter an If parameter is true then

```
MsgBox"Please go back and check...."
```

Im just not sure what should follow the if....

Any pointers would be very much appreciated.

Comment: see [this](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/vba-macros/highlight-cells-based-on-a-condition/) to get started. In `If InStr(1, cell, searchTerm, vbTextCompare) Then ` you need to change `cell` to `cell.text` and it should work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try below code

```
Sub DisplayError()

On Error Resume Next
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sheets("Location_Multiple").Range("A1:AL10000")

Dim rngError As Range
Set rngError = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)

If Not rngError Is Nothing Then
    For Each cell In rngError
        MsgBox "Please go back and check.... " & cell.Address
    Next
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect..worked a treat,, sorry to ask another question still being a VBA newbie, what is the clasue to show a box if there is no error?

Answer (score 1):

Use this, change the `LookIn` argument to `xlValues` instead of `xlFormulas`:

```
Selection.Find(What:="#REF!", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

For a bit cleaner implementation:

```
Dim sht as Worksheet
Dim rngSrch as Range
Dim rngErr as Range

Set sht = Sheets("Location_Multiple")
Set rngSrch = sht.Range("A1:AL10000")

Set rngErr = rngSearch.Find(What:="#REF!", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not rngErr Is Nothing Then
    'Do something to the offending cell, like, highlight it:
    rngErr.Interior.ColorIndex = 39
End If
```

Anticipating there may be multiple cells with an error like this, you'll probably have to implement your `.Find` within a `Do...While` loop.  There are several examples of that sort of problem on SO.  If you have trouble implementing the loop, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is because you're searching for a string - whereas `#REF` is an error.

You could use the [IsError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s55kc30t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function, to return true for a cell with an error. Combine this with a loop, and you could achieve what you require. I haven't tested this, but you get the jist:

```
Set rng = Sheets("Location_Multiple").Range("A1:AL10000")
For Each cell In rngError
    If IsError(cell) == true
    MsgBox "Please go back and check.... " & cell.Address
    Endif
Next
```

Comment: True. I didn't want to do all the homework. Exception handling would also be another feasible option. Depends how much work the OP wants to put in.

Comment: only use one `=` in VBA :)